# Winform: Why can't I move instanciation out of InitializeComponent?

Tags: c#, winforms

Visual Studio created this code:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
```

I just want to do this instead:

```
    private void instantiate()
    {

        this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        instantiate();
```

The program compile and execute but Visual Studio cannot draw the control on the winform any more. How to fix this ?

Update: I know that the code is generated automatically but why on earth when executed at Run-Time not at design time it doesn't execute as normal c# code ?

I really suspect that Microsoft like Apple is making everything hard for coders to tight them to their ide you must be really Sherlock Holmes to enquiry :)

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/interprocess-communication-snooping.html

Comment: Any particular reason *why* you want to do this? You really should not be modifying the `InitializeComponent` method anyway. That code is auto-generated by the designer, and prefers to be left alone.

Comment: Because I want to organize code my way :) and even generate it myself so it's easier when I do create separate modules which will be in partial classes.

Comment: @user310291: trust me on this one - Microsoft just isn't in Apple's league when it comes to making things difficult for coders.

Answer (score 4):

`InitializeComponent()` is a method automatically generated by the designer. If you modify it, the designer may be unable to load your control and other funny things may occur.

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a multiple platform project and I tried to have same code organization. This Visual Studio dependency is annoying for me. Above all I can't see no reason why they did like this, it's kind of proprietary on purpose for no real reason than protectionism.

Answer (score 2):

Note the error message that the designer shows:

> Method 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.instantiate' not found.

It is complaining about the *Form* class not having an *instantiate* method  Not your form derived class which does have the method.  That's inevitable, the type doesn't yet exist until it is deserialized, it can only reflect on base class members.

But yeah, don't do this, your code is going to get stomped as soon as the designer re-serializes the form and regenerates the InitializeComponent() method.  Editing that method is guaranteed lossage.  Why you'd want to do is isn't clear.  You could create a base form with a custom constructor and inherit from that.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio only shows whats in your *.designer.cs file. If you move something outside of it, it won't know what controls you want to display.

If you create a control outside of the InitializeComponent, don't forget to add it to the [Control collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) of the Form.

```
this.Controls.Add(trackBar1);
```

Comment: What "know" means ? If he call InitializeComponent why isn't able to call a function within it ?

Comment: It means that Visual Studio reads the `InitializeComponent` to figure out how to render the control. As soon as you move a control initialization outside of this function, Visual Studio won't *know* anything outside of it, i.e. it will not display it. And as others have mentioned, `InitializeComponent` will be regenerated when it displays the designer so modifying it will not help either. You can call instansiate after the call to `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor instead like MusiGenesis suggested.

Comment: But why on earth doesn't Visual Studio just EXECUTE the method as one would expect for a function code instead of PARSING this section ? The rational reason is just plain commercial reason: avoid you to use anything else than Visual Studio.

Comment: @user310291: You can read a bit more at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2004/12/12/280823.aspx. You don't *have* to use the Visual Studio designer. If you never open it the code will not be regenerated, so if you run your application, it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add controls etc. to your form without using the designer, then do so in your `instantiate()` method, but call `instantiate()` from your control's constructor, rather than by editing the `InitializeComponent()` method.

It is never ever ever a good idea to manually edit a method created and maintained by the IDE (for that matter, manually editing *any* code that comes from a code generator is going to get you in trouble).

Comment: @user310291: How did it not work? If it's not showing when you start your application, did you add the control to your forms Control collection as I suggested in my answer? If by "not working" you mean that it will not show in Visual Studios designer, then your easiest choice is to add your trackbar control via the designer instead of trying to do it yourself in code.

Comment: Calling your method from the constructor probably doesn't work because of the ` this.trackBar1 = new ...` line, because `trackBar1` is a control you've added in the designer, which means it won't exist until *after* `InitializeComponent` runs. If you want to add controls in your code, don't add them in the designer.